# How to correctly remove items from QGraphicsItemGroup

Tags: qt, qt5

I have an application that draws the route of our drone on the map. The route is a set of points and lines that are stored in a `QGraphicsItemGroup` object. Every time the drone moves there is another point and a line added using [addToGroup()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitemgroup.html#addToGroup) method. However, after some time the size of group and the associated drawing process becomes extremely taxing on the host system.

What is the efficient way to limit the size of the `QGraphicsItemGroup`?

- Limit the number of items a group object can contain by using some methods in `QGraphicsItemGroup`?
- I will have to remove the old items manually? There are two methods I was considering: Use `QGraphicsItem::childItems()` to get the list of items in the group and then delete the first one using `QGraphicsItemGroup::removeFromGroup`

Comment: Approximately (order of magnitude) how many items before performance degrades?

Comment: I looked at the source for QGraphicsItemGroup::addToGroup. It seems to me that your plan for removing items won't work, as the function just parents the items: it doesn't remember the order. Therefore if you want a queue, you need to maintain it yourself. I'd strongly recommend using a profiler to find exactly where your performance problems are.

Comment: 6000. The problem is that the group keeps increasing. I've tried the proposed algorithm with `childItems` and `removeFromGroup` and it works fine.